# How to refer to sibling component in react js with useIntersection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const FirstPage = ()=>{
    return(
        <>
        <Header />
        <SlideShow/>
        <PrimaryContent/>
        <SeconderyContent/>
        </>
    )
}
```

this is the parent component of both slideshow and primarycontent

```
 const PrimaryContent = () => {
 const sectionRef = useRef(null)
    const intersection = useIntersection(sectionRef,{
      root : null,
      rootMargin : '0px',
      threshold: 0.5
    })
```

and I've writed this code in primarycontent but I don't want root to be viewport so
is there a way to
refer to slideshow component in here?